# Retrieving XML model from external JAR using Wro4J Maven Plugin

Tags: java, jar, maven-plugin, wro4j

I want to load resources from an external JAR file using Wro4J 1.7.6. I need to do so at compile time, so I added the [Wro4J Maven plugin](https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/MavenPlugin).

If I extract the resources (js, css and the another-wro.xml) into my project folder in Eclipse, the files are minimized and merged, as I want them to be. But if I try to [import the another-wro.xml by classpath](https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/WroFileFormat#Import_directive), from a seperated JAR, I am getting a "No valid model was found!" message.

**Detailed Error**

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't get InputStream from this resource: classpath:META-INF/resources/wro/another-wro.xml
```

My **WEB-INF/wro.xml** (from my project, having the jar as a dependency)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<groups xmlns="http://www.isdc.ro/wro">

 <import>classpath:META-INF/resources/wro/another-wro.xml</import>

 <group name='main'>
  ...
 </group>
</groups>
```

I added the external JAR as a dependency and made sure it contains the folders and files mentioned above. If the JAR is in place and available at compile time, shouldn't the another-wro.xml file be loadable?

Comment: Though I'm not sure, it could be caused by a known issue related to this issue: https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/issues/detail?id=627&start=100. 

Either way, it would help if you could create a quick-start project which would reproduce the bug.